BroadcastReceiver does not work in the application
Recently I faced a problem I added a broadcast intent receiver to show wifi state changes
my java class:
package com.example.myapplication;

import static android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION;
import static android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;
//public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver
public class WiFiDirectActivity extends Activity{
   // DeviceActionListener implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener
    public static final String TAG = "wifidirectdemo";
//    private boolean isWifiP2pEnabled = false;
//    private boolean retryChannel = false;
//    public Context context;
//    private final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
//    private WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
//    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    /**
     * @param isWifiP2pEnabled the isWifiP2pEnabled to set
     */
//    public void setIsWifiP2pEnabled(boolean isWifiP2pEnabled) {
//        this.isWifiP2pEnabled = isWifiP2pEnabled;
//    }
    private WifiP2pManager mWifiP2pManager;
    private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
    public String Instance_name = "xxxxxx";
    String Instance_Type = "yyy._tcp";

    public static class WiFiDirectReceive extends BroadcastReceiver {
        //        WiFiDirectBroadcastReceive t = new WiFiDirectBroadcastReceive();
        WifiP2pManager manager;
        WifiP2pManager.Channel channel;
        Context context1;

        public WiFiDirectReceive(WifiP2pManager manager, WifiP2pManager.Channel channel, Context context1) {
            this.manager = manager;
            this.channel = channel;
            this.context1 = context1;

//            @Override
//            public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
//
//            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Toast mess = new Toast(context);
            mess.setText(action);
            mess.show();
//            Instance_name =action;
//            if (action.equals(WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
//                int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
//                if (state != WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
//                        Toast mess = new Toast(context);
//                        mess.setText("no");
//                        mess.show();
//                } else {
//                        Toast mess = new Toast(context);
//                        mess.setText("ok!");
//                        mess.show();
//                }
//
//            } else if (action.equals(WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION)) {
//
//            } else {
//            }

        }
    }
    public class fail extends WiFiDirectActivity implements WifiP2pManager.ChannelListener {

        @Override
        public void onChannelDisconnected() {
            Toast.makeText(this,"disconnect!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    @Override/*       .   de  m   o   2  s.    c  om  */
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);

        mWifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
//        mWifiP2pManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
        System.out.println(mWifiP2pManager);

        mChannel = mWifiP2pManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), new fail());
        mReceiver = new WiFiDirectReceive(mWifiP2pManager, mChannel, this);
        Toast.makeText(this,mIntentFilter.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(this,mReceiver.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    }

    /** register the BroadcastReceiver with the intent values to be matched */
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        try{
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter,RECEIVER_EXPORTED);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"none",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this,"exc",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
//        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // дерегистрируем (выключаем) BroadcastReceiver
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
    /**
     * Remove all peers and clear all fields. This is called on
     * BroadcastReceiver receiving a state change event.
     */


    }

and also specified intentions in manifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
        tools:ignore="GradleOverrides" />
    <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"
        tools:ignore="ReservedSystemPermission" />
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission
        android:required="true"
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        tools:targetApi="30">
<!--        <receiver-->
<!--            android:name="WiFiDirectReceive"-->
<!--            android:enabled="true"-->
<!--            android:exported="true"-->
<!--            tools:ignore="Instantiatable">-->
<!--            <intent-filter>-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />-->
<!--                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED" />-->
<!--            </intent-filter>-->
<!--        </receiver>-->
        <activity
            android:name=".WiFiDirectActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION" />
                                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.p2p.STATE_CHANGED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

as I found out this code does not work after registering my receiver

everything works fine in the emulator (android api 30) in Android Studio
but when I test on a real device (if needed it's redmi 9 and huawei psmart) the application starts and closes I didn't get an error window
I tried to register the receiver in manifest.xml but that didn't work either, tell me what to do

Please [edit] the question to provide the stacktrace from logcat.
